# Automatically transferring info from Casenote to indivudial client form

Tags: wordpress, contacts, custom-fields, civicase

How do I automatically populate the individual contact form with information from the case note (civicase)? I'm using Wordpress.

I'm using civicases for our intake sheets and I've chosen that because I want a single computer form to take the information down. I know I can use profiles new individual to populate the client information but I need some information in both the case note and the client form. 
I'm looking for a way to automatically include the information,which is collected through custom fields into the newly created individual and to do the reverse if the client calls back (i.e that info collected automatically populates into the case note).

any advice?

Comment: Hi Rowan - welcome to SE. Can you clarify a bit more of your process as Civi can be used in many different ways. What do you mean by 'case note' (not a phrase i am familiar with and we have worked with civicase for several clients), also want do you mean by 'populate the contact with info from the case note', and again your 'intake sheet'. urls, screenshots and navigational clues can all help others figure what you mean. eg on dmaster i can Open Case, via Cases > New Case, and on that select the 'client', and in doing so use the New Individual profile to add data.

Comment: and i could if i wanted add new fields to the New Individual profile so i can create the type of form I want. eg I can add fields to that profile via http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/uf/group/field?reset=1&action=browse&gid=4

Answer (score 1):

if the process you are using is via New Case, then you get the option to Add New Individual if the contact does not exist.

In that case you can modify the New Individual profile and add additional core or custom fields to that so you can add the info you require to your contact.